# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playwright.sync_api'; 'playwright' is not a package on Windows

Tags: python, playwright

I am just to try to follow the examples from [text](https://pypi.org/project/playwright/).
I have already installed playwright using:

```
pip install playwright
playwright install
```

I tried to run the python code using:
`python test.py`
But I encountered following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playwright.sync_api'; 
'playwright' is not a package
```

I'd like any advice or help.
Thanks in advance.

I uninstalled the playwright module and installed again but the same error.

Comment: Are you using the same interpreter for pip and for your script ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if your `python` command and `pip` command are linked to the same python interpreter.
Use:

- `pip --version`
- `where python` and see the first line